# a program to calculate values of an input function

Tags: function

I have encountered a problem in my homework. my homework is about writting a program to approximate a solution of an input function ( of form : `f(x) = 0`, for example `x*sinx -2 = 0` ). Of course, the concept of function is so immense, my teacher limited it to basic functions which are composed of continuous basic subfunctions such as `sin`, `cos`, `log`, exponent, square root... I intend to use genetic algorithm to solve this problem, however how can I calculate this function at some values of variables? because the function is entered by user, it is in form of string. The function can be so complex that makes it hard to caculate for example

```
f(x) = 1/(x-2) + sin (sqrt (1/x  + 1))...
```

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a place to get people to do your homework for you. We are however willing to *help* if you make a demonstrable effort.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. I just tried adding it myself, but it's apparently deprecated and in the process of being removed. The tag's wiki says it shouldn't be added to questions. Worth knowing for the future.

Comment: @Saladin Akara I didn't know of that change in the hoomework tag. Thank you for commenting it here.